# Populating listbox on page load

Tags: c#

Im attempting to populate a listbox from a database on form load, but when i load the form no data appears. The connection to the database is setup in VS 2017 and thats where I got the connection string.

```
namespace listbox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fillListBox();
        }

        void fillListBox()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=computername\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=footfall;Integrated Security=True";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select category from category",con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            categoryBox.Items.Clear();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                categoryBox.Items.Add(reader.ToString());
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions thrown? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Do you really have a column named the same as the table?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you just need to change this... `categoryBox.Items.Add(reader["category"].ToString());` <-- you need to specify the column name.

Comment: Also, don't use the load event.  Do that in the constructor.  Load event can hide some exceptions.

Comment: FCin I do, just learning.  Thanks for the comments, they help me to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want [`reader.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)(which returns the type name) but [`reader.GetString(0)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    categoryBox.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
}
```

Comment: This worked great.  Thanks.  I thought I needed to convert the type of reader to a string.

Comment: @DavidFolksman well, the reader provides access to all fields of the current record. You only select one column here but you could have selected multiple, then a ToString would be useless(which column you want?).

Comment: I want to loop through all columns and display the values one line after another